# Handle OnPress inside React-Native navigationOptions

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I'm stuck in adding save method inside `navigationOptions` can you please help me to do right way.

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
        headerTitle: "Add New Item",
        ...css.header,
        headerRight: <NavViewRight
            onPress={() => this.rightHeaderAction()} />,
    })
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually it's not clear what exactly you try to do.
But seems like you want to call a non-static method inside class from static method.

You referring to `this`, but `this` here not means class instance. In order to call something from your class you need to make method static.

Something like this:

```
class MyScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({
        navigation
    }) => ({
        headerTitle: "Add New Item",
        ...css.header,
        headerRight: < NavViewRight
        onPress = {
            () => MyScreen.rightHeaderAction()
        }
        />,
    })

    static rightHeaderAction() {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: It's still static though if anyone is wondering why you can't interface 'this' inside the static function.